# How can I strip partial/incorrect tags from input?

Tags: php, strip-tags

I have a script that remove the html tags. It works OK with some cases such as:

```
<p>Test</p>
```

or

```
<p><b>Test</b></p>
```

. This is my script:

```
function safeStrip($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('/</', ' <', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/>/', '> ', $text);
    $desc = strip_tags($text);
    $desc = preg_replace('/  /', ' ', $desc);
    return $desc;
}
```

However if the user type

```
<pTest</p>
```

or

```
<p Test</p>
```

or

```
<p>Test/p>
```

....
The script make my string is blank. If the user input the html tags (complete or not complete tags). The script will identify and remove.

Comment: Are you sure you want this kind of behavior?
Why not just removing the complete tags?
Removing incomplete tags may cause you some problems if someone uses this character ">"

Comment: Thank you for your replying. But my customers make a test case like that. I tried to explain but he does not accept.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this,

```
$text = '<p>Test</p>';
echo strip_tags($text);
```

This will help you to remove HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all Tags `strip_tags` is the way to go. If you only want to remove some then take a look at [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org)

As for your cases, what the expected result for `<pTest</p>` and `<p Test</p>`?

Comment: Thank you. In my cases, I need to get the text in html tag.